# Web scraping with Python BeautifulSoup returning different HTML than expected

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to do some web scraping on a surf report website using BeautifulSoup, but the returned html does not appear to match the html when viewed in a browser, meaning I can't scrape the data that I am looking for.
I am trying to scrape from the following website on the "quiver-surf-height" class, which contains the local surf height estimate.
https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/paradise-beach/584204214e65fad6a7709cc1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.surfline.com/surf-report/paradise-beach/584204214e65fad6a7709cc1"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

print(soup.select(".quiver-surf-height"))
```

The print statement returns an empty list. Reading through the returned html I found a statement "Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page." I'm following the steps laid out in a class, so I'm not sure how to handle this response. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: The page HTML is likely dynamically generated by the browser using JavaScript. To scrape the resulting HTML you will need something like [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the data you're after is generated dynamically, however, there's an API you can query to get what you want.

All you need it the `surf spot id` and how much of days-worth data you want. By default it comes for the last 16 days in an 1-hour intervals. But you can change these params too.

For example, this gets last two days of surf height data served per every hour.

```py
import datetime

import requests

surf_sopt_id = "584204214e65fad6a7709cc1"
days = "2"
api_url = f"https://services.surfline.com/kbyg/spots/forecasts/wave?spotId={surf_sopt_id}&days={days}&intervalHours=1"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()

for day in data["data"]["wave"]:
    _time = (
        datetime
        .datetime
        .fromtimestamp(day['timestamp'])
        .strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    )
    print(f"{_time}")
    surf = day["surf"]
    print(f"Surf: {surf['min']} - {surf['max']}")
    print(f"{surf['humanRelation']}")
```

Output:

```
2022-09-25 06:00:00
Surf: 0.9 - 1.4
Waist to shoulder
2022-09-25 07:00:00
Surf: 0.9 - 1.4
Waist to shoulder
2022-09-25 08:00:00
Surf: 0.9 - 1.4
Waist to shoulder
2022-09-25 09:00:00
Surf: 0.9 - 1.2
Waist to chest
2022-09-25 10:00:00
Surf: 0.9 - 1.2
Waist to chest
2022-09-25 11:00:00
Surf: 0.9 - 1.2
Waist to chest
2022-09-25 12:00:00
Surf: 0.9 - 1.2
Waist to chest
2022-09-25 13:00:00
Surf: 0.9 - 1.2
Waist to chest
2022-09-25 14:00:00
Surf: 0.6 - 1.1
Thigh to stomach
2022-09-25 15:00:00
Surf: 0.6 - 1.1
Thigh to stomach
2022-09-25 16:00:00

and more ...
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Is this API created by Surfline to cater to web scraping? If not, where did this API come from, and is this something that I can find by myself in the future?

Comment: The API is created by Surfline to *serve* the content you see on the page. This is a very common practice. You can find the API endpoint in your browser. Go to Devloper Tools -> Network -> XHR.